# Restful webservices in Django

Tags: python, web-services, restful-authentication

I want to implement resful web services for a authenticating system on Django. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Although i tried to understand through some tutorial. Still i can't get the actual concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)? This makes it quite simple to hook a RESTful API to your existing Django application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in answer to [this relate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488325/framework-for-implementing-rest-web-service-in-django), also have a look at [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/), it provides authentication support via OAuth.